# CN1 - login with google/facebook leave underlying form active

Tags: codenameone, google-signin

This problem is occurring in the simulator, when I click the login with google button the google entry dialog is shown, but when I try to click on the field to enter my google ID the (facebook login) button on the original form behind the field gets triggered. My code is pretty much copied from the socialchat demo with the exception of two buttons (my system login, register to my system). Other issues that I am having that might be related are I had to set the force login to true or code runs as if it is logged in already (with null values for name, id, etc.). I cannot get the button to retain the border changes (also true for facebook button). The Start and doLogin code is as supplied in the demo with a few System.out.println statements I added for debugging.

```
    private void showLoginForm() {

        Form loginForm = new Form();

    // the blue theme styles the title area normally this is good but in this case we don't want the blue bar at the top
        loginForm.getTitleArea().setUIID("Container");
        loginForm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        loginForm.setUIID("MainForm");
        Container cnt = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        cnt.setUIID("Padding"); 
        Button loginWithGoogle = new Button("Signin with Google");
        loginWithGoogle.setUIID("LoginButtonGoogle");
        Button loginWithFacebook = new Button("Signin with Facebook");
        loginWithFacebook.setUIID("LoginButtonFacebook");
        Style iconFontStyle = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("IconFont");
        loginWithFacebook.setIcon(FontImage.create(" \ue96c ", iconFontStyle));
        loginWithGoogle.setIcon(FontImage.create(" \ue976 ", iconFontStyle));    
        Button myLoginBtn = new Button("");
        FontImage.setMaterialIcon(myLoginBtn, FontImage.MATERIAL_LINK);
        myLoginBtn.setUIID("ButtonLogin");
        Button registerBtn = new Button("Register");
        registerBtn.setUIID("ButtonRegister");
        cnt.addComponent(myLoginBtn);
        cnt.addComponent(loginWithGoogle);
        cnt.addComponent(loginWithFacebook); 
        cnt.addComponent(registerBtn);        
        loginWithGoogle.addActionListener((e) -> {
                Dialog.show("Test", "Test", "OK", null);
                tokenPrefix = "google";
                Login gc = GoogleConnect.getInstance();
                gc.setScope("profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
                gc.setClientId("----------.apps.googleusercontent.com");
                gc.setRedirectURI("http://barq.appspot.com/oauth2callback");
                gc.setClientSecret("--------");
//                doLogin(gc, new GoogleData(), false);
                doLogin(gc, new GoogleData(), true);                
                System.out.println("The fullname is; " + fullName);
                //doLogin(GoogleConnect.getInstance());
            });

        loginWithFacebook.addActionListener((e) -> {
                System.out.println("Facebook action listener");
                tokenPrefix = "facebook";
                Login fb = FacebookConnect.getInstance();
                fb.setClientId("--------------");
                fb.setRedirectURI("http://www.barq.appspot.com/");
                fb.setClientSecret("--------------");
//                doLogin(fb, new FacebookData(), false);
                doLogin(fb, new FacebookData(), true);
                System.out.println("The fullname is; " + fullName);
                //doLogin(FacebookConnect.getInstance());
            });

        myLoginBtn.addActionListener((e) -> {
                System.out.println("In actionListener for myLoginBtn of base app");
                CustLogin custlogin = new CustLogin();
                custlogin.show();
                return;
        });

        registerBtn.addActionListener((e) -> {
                System.out.println("In actionListener for registerBtn of base app");
                execute("https://barq.appspot.com/signup");
        });

        loginForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, cnt);
        System.out.println("About to show loginForm");
        loginForm.show();
```

Comment: I think this might be a regression due to the recent changes to the include z-order for native peer support. We might need a fix for that. I suggest filing an issue to make sure it doesn't fall between the cracks

Comment: GoogleConnect will show a new form with an embedded webview when you call its `doLogin()` method.  There shouldn't be anything "behind" it.  Do you actually see the facebook button behind the google login page?  Try debugging, and place a break point in your facebook button's action listener to see call stack when it is called.  That will offer some clues.

Comment: I do not see the facebook, or google buttons until I click on the "Email or phone" textbox on the Google login dialog. Is there anything specific in the stack I should look for?